# Its throwing error , when I try to Download python-espeak

Tags: pip, espeak

This is what iam getting when I tried to install it. Is there any solution for this. There is an error while building the wheel for python-espeak. I have used the command `pip install python-espeak`

```
C:\Users\akhil>pip install python-espeak
        Collecting python-espeak
          Downloading python-espeak-0.6.3.tar.gz (9.1 kB)
          Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
        Building wheels for collected packages: python-espeak
          Building wheel for python-espeak (setup.py) ... error
          error: subprocess-exited-with-error
        × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
          │ exit code: 1
          ╰─> [10 lines of output]
              running bdist_wheel
              running build
              running build_py
              creating build
              creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
              creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\espeak
              copying espeak\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\espeak
              running build_ext
              building 'espeak.core' extension
              error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
              [end of output]
        
          note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
          ERROR: Failed building wheel for python-espeak
          Running setup.py clean for python-espeak
        Failed to build python-espeak
        Installing collected packages: python-espeak
          Running setup.py install for python-espeak ... error
          error: subprocess-exited-with-error
        
          × Running setup.py install for python-espeak did not run successfully.
          │ exit code: 1
          ╰─> [10 lines of output]
              running install
              running build
              running build_py
              creating build
              creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
              creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\espeak
              copying espeak\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\espeak
              running build_ext
              building 'espeak.core' extension
              error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
              [end of output]
        
          note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
        error: legacy-install-failure
        
        × Encountered error while trying to install package.
        ╰─> python-espeak
        
        note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
        hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

Comment: error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/

Comment: And for the future: you need to compile https://espeak.sourceforge.net/